# Chrome drop down menu bug (Closing automatically)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have been getting a problem where my drop down menu is not working. Whenever I try to open a drop down menu it closes it automatically within a second. It used to work fine and I have not downloaded anything that should affect it.

I have tried:

- Re-installing Chrome
- Checked for malware with Chrome and all other trusted anti malware software
- Disabled all extensions and tried incognito mode
- Installed Google Canary with same issue still appearing
- Cleared history and cache.
- Updated Chrome to the newest version

I have tried every single thing I could find as solution but with no success. It started a few months ago and I am not sure why.
The issue is Chrome only and does not happen in Firefox or Microsoft Edge.

This issue happens on every site with drop down menus.

If anyone knows the solution to this it would be amazing.

[image]

The issue is in PNG attached file

Comment: Maybe there's some problem with your keyboard...? Try disconnect it and see if it still happens. Also check `chrome://flags/` and check if you changed anything there

Comment: its laptop also tried without keyboard still the same also reset chrome://flags/ still no difference.. it happens to all sites mostly there are few sites which are normal but on most sites doing the same. i also remove whole chrome and reinstall it but still the same..... i dont want to reinstall windows thats the thing left....

Comment: @MuhammadMohsin do you have a Huion drawing tablet? A lot of people have reported this issue when the Huion control panel is running in the background.

Answer (score 3):

Huion tablet is the culprit in my case, the symptom is gone if I close the huion tablet app.

Comment: wow. never expected this. this fixed my problem. thanks!